# Domain of $f(x) = 0x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What's the domain of $f(x) = 0x$? It seems to me that it'd be a member of the set of all numbers, but I haven't seen a way of representing such a set.

Comment: do you mean $f(x)=0$?

Comment: More generally, the function $f(x) = c$ is a straight line, because for all values of x the y-value stays constant. Therefore the domain is all real values of x.

Comment: I thought they were the same thing - I only included it for the sake of having an x present on the right hand side as well.

Comment: Doesn't the function hold for complex, quaternions, etc? Surely it holds for any type of number?

Comment: If you just give a formula, especially one as vague as this one, the question "what's the domain of $f$" is not well-posed. It could be pretty much anything. What usually happens is that this is asked of high school students and it actually means "what is the maximal set of real numbers for which this expression makes sense and gives a real number". In which case the answer would be "the set of real numbers".

Comment: All numbers? What is a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function is a triplet $(X,Y,f)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are domain and codomain, respectively, while $f$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ such that $(\forall x\in X)(\exists! y\in Y)\ (x,y) \in f$. Note that we usually write $f(x) = y$ instead of $(x,y)\in f$, but this is irrelevant. What is relevant is that you haven't defined function at all and it is impossible to specify domain of such a thing.

You might be confused by exercises such as "Find natural domain of [...]" where it is implicitly assumed that you are looking at functions of the form $f\colon A\to \mathbb R$, $A\subseteq \mathbb R$.

But, let us look at when does $f(x) = 0x$ make sense. First of all, notation $0x$ suggests that we are looking at a member of some ring. Thus, let $R$ be any ring. So, what could be domain of such a function? The answer is any subset $S$ of the ring $R$! So, formula $f(x) = 0x$ makes sense for any function of the form $f:S\to R$, where $R$ is a ring, and $S\subseteq R$.

Of course, I might have been mislead by the notation, it might be that $0$ is a letter of some alphabet, and we are actually looking at function that takes a word of some free monoid and adds letter "$0$" at its front. In short, there is no way to know what you even meant without context.

Comment: Or, a function is a collection of ordered pairs satisfying an additional property.